# jQuery datepicker date picking issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Live website- http://www.danfords.com/

I am using 2 different BOOK NOW form(you can see it on top right), one for Desktop version & one for Tablet/Smartphone version(resize browser windows then Book now form will be Collapse).

Tablet/Smartphone version date-picker blocked out past dates so that you could not select dates prior to today. Also, if you selected a future date for check-in, it would block out previous dates when you select check-out so you don't have to find those dates again.

But that is not working on Desktop version form. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Post your code here. None of us is going to dig for it on your website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It only works on your mobile version Arrival field because thats the only one you declared a minDate on.

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    minDate:0,
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
    }
});
```

You would need to add that `minDate:0,` line to your `$("#datepicker3")` datpicker initialization as well, like so.

```
$( "#datepicker3" ).datepicker({
    minDate:0,
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#datepicker4" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
    }
});


$( "#datepicker4" ).datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#datepicker3" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
    }
});
```

Also notice i made some fixes to your onClose events as well, datepicker3 and datepicker4 were pointing back to datepicker, which is incorrect.  this even updates the other datepickers enabled and disabled days based on the day selected in its related datepicker.

Answer (score 2):

In your site.js file you only added the minDate method of the smartphone Datepicker input fields. You also have to set this setting for the desktop datepicker input fields. Like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   $('#datepicker, #datepicker2, #datepicker3, #datepicker4').datepicker({
   minDate: 0,
});
```